# Get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation fails giving error :response status code does not indicate success 404

Tags: powershell

Through Release pipeline in Azure we deploy task to create classification

```
# Remove .database.windows.net from server name 
$serverName = $serverName.ToLower().Replace(".database.windows.net","")
Get-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityRecommendation -ResourceGroupName$resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $databaseName  | Set-AzSqlDatabaseSensitivityClassification
```

which fails giving error Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)

I tried the solutiom mentioned in https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12304.

But when we run this it give message WARNING: The version '2.9.1' of module 'Az.Accounts' is currently in use. .

How to fix this .